# Power BI - divide COUNT by DISTINCTCOUNT

Tags: count, powerbi, distinct, measure

How can I create a Measure in Power BI to divide COUNT by DISTINCTCOUNT of the same thing?

**Example:**
**Source data - only one column:**

- PERSON

  - A
  - A
  - A
  - B
  - B
  - C

**Now I want to show the following result:**

- PERSON ... APPEARANCES
- A ... 3
- B ... 2
- C ... 1

If I try this by APPEARANCES = COUNT(PERSON) / DISTINCTCOUNT(PERSON), that doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Using your example data the formula works, what's is the 'error'/'why if deosn't work' you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

After loading the data into power bi, go to edit queries--> In the home tab--> select group by--> A window will appear asking for : on which column you would like to group the data.

Please refer the below pic.

[image]

[image]